# How do I make a Scalaz ZIO lazy?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, scalaz, io-monad, zio

I have a heavy side-effecting function (think database call) that I want to use as a lazy value, so that it gets called only on first use (and not at all if never used).

How do I do this with ZIO?

If my program looks like this, the function gets called only once (but even the result is not used at all):

```
import scalaz.zio.IO
import scalaz.zio.console._

object Main extends scalaz.zio.App {

  def longRunningDbAction: IO[Nothing, Integer] = for {
    _ <- putStrLn("Calling the database now")
  } yield 42

  def maybeUseTheValue(x: Integer): IO[Nothing, Unit] = for {
    _ <- putStrLn(s"The database said ${x}")
  } yield ()

  def maybeNeedItAgain(x: Integer): IO[Nothing, Unit] = for {
    _ <- putStrLn("Okay, we did not need it again here.")
  } yield ()

 override def run(args: List[String]): IO[Nothing, Main.ExitStatus] = for {
    valueFromDb <- longRunningDbAction
    _ <- maybeUseTheValue(valueFromDb)
    _ <- maybeNeedItAgain(valueFromDb)
  } yield ExitStatus.ExitNow(0)

}
```

I suppose I have to pass an `IO` that produces the `Int` instead of the already materialized `Int`, but if I pass in the original `IO` that just calls the database, it will be called repeatedly:

```
object Main extends scalaz.zio.App {

  def longRunningDbAction: IO[Nothing, Integer] = for {
    _ <- putStrLn("Calling the database now")
  } yield 42


  def maybeUseTheValue(x: IO[Nothing, Integer]): IO[Nothing, Unit] = for {
    gettingItNow <- x
    _ <- putStrLn(s"The database said ${gettingItNow}")
  } yield ()

  def maybeNeedItAgain(x: IO[Nothing, Integer]): IO[Nothing, Unit] = for {
    gettingItNow <- x
    _ <- putStrLn(s"Okay, we need it again here: ${gettingItNow}")
  } yield ()

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[Nothing, Main.ExitStatus] = for {
    _ <- maybeUseTheValue(longRunningDbAction)
    _ <- maybeNeedItAgain(longRunningDbAction)
  } yield ExitStatus.ExitNow(0)

}
```

Is there a way to "wrap" the `longRunningDbAction` into something that makes it lazy?

Comment: What determines if you need to call the DB again? Is it something that is determined in the first call out?

Comment: @user3056052 It is supposed to work like a regular `lazy val dbResult = callDatabase()` in Scala, i.e. be evaluated the first time it is called and afterwards just return the same value again (without doing anything else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZIO has [memoize](https://static.javadoc.io/dev.zio/zio_2.12/1.0.0-RC9-4/zio/ZIO.html#memoize:zio.ZIO[R,Nothing,zio.IO[E,A]]) now.

```
override def run(args: List[String]): IO[Nothing, Main.ExitStatus] = for {
   valueFromDb <- ZIO.memoize(longRunningDbAction)
   _ <- maybeUseTheValue(valueFromDb)
   _ <- maybeNeedItAgain(valueFromDb)
} yield ExitStatus.ExitNow(0)
```

It does essentially the same thing as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53869931/14955): Source looks like this

```
/**
   * Returns an effect that, if evaluated, will return the lazily computed result
   * of this effect.
   */
  final def memoize: ZIO[R, Nothing, IO[E, A]] =
    for {
      r <- ZIO.environment[R]
      p <- Promise.make[E, A]
      l <- Promise.make[Nothing, Unit]
      _ <- (l.await *> ((self provide r) to p)).fork
    } yield l.succeed(()) *> p.await
```

Comment: The main difference to the other answer is that it also captured the resource, so that using the lazy value does not need the `R` (only creating it does).

Answer (score 4):

I came up with the following:

```
 def lazyIO[E,A](io: IO[E,A]): IO[Nothing, IO[E, A]] = {
    for {
      barrier <- Promise.make[Nothing, Unit]
      fiber <- (barrier.get *> io).fork
    } yield barrier.complete(()) *> putStrLn("getting it") *> fiber.join
  }
```

**Updated version for ZIO 1.0-RC4 (with Environment support)**:

```
def lazyIO[R, E, A](io: ZIO[R, E, A]): ZIO[R, Nothing, ZIO[R, E, A]] = {
  for {
    barrier <- Promise.make[Nothing, Unit]
    fiber <- (barrier.await *> io).fork
  } yield barrier.succeed(()) *> fiber.join
}
```

So this is an IO that takes an IO and returns a lazy version of it.

It works by starting a `fiber` that runs the original `io`, but only after a Promise (`barrier`) has been completed.

The lazy IO first completes that `barrier` (which if it was the first one to do this will unblock the `fiber` which in turn runs the wrapped `io`) and then joins the `fiber` to retrieve the calculation result.

With this, I can do

```
override def run(args: List[String]): IO[Nothing, Main.ExitStatus] = for {
    valueFromDb <- lazyIO(longRunningDbAction)
    _ <- maybeUseTheValue(valueFromDb)
    _ <- maybeNeedItAgain(valueFromDb)
  } yield ExitStatus.ExitNow(0)
```

And the console output shows that indeed the lazy value gets pulled twice but only the first one triggers the "database access":

```
getting it
Calling the database now
The database said 42
getting it
Okay, we need it again here: 42
```

Comment: Why not add `).flatten` at the end to avoid the ZIO or ZIO as return type ? And it did not seem to work for me it is being call several times

Comment: @Wonay: I think it has to be a ZIO of a ZIO, because it is an effectful function (creating a promise) that produces another effectful function (which will complete the promise). But I might be wrong.   Can you post the code that does not work for you somewhere?

Comment: I call the `LazyIO(...)` in two for-comprehension and it is executed twice. I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944089/zio-how-to-compute-only-once

Comment: Yes, that does not work. You are supposed to call `lazyIO` only once, which gives you another ZIO that you can then call repeatedly. That's what I meant by not being able to flatten this. I have to look at the `memoize` thing mentioned in that thread.

Comment: Note that this `memoize` also has the same kind of ZIO of ZIO signature.