# ZIO : How to compute only once?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, zio

I am using ZIO: https://github.com/zio/zio

in my `build.sbt`:

```
"dev.zio" %% "zio" % "1.0.0-RC9"
```

No matter what I tried, my results are always being computed each time I need them:

```
val t = Task {
  println(s"Compute")
  12
}

    val r = unsafeRun(for {
      tt1 <- t
      tt2 <- t
    } yield {
      tt1 + tt2
    })

    println(r)
```

For this example, the log look like :

```
Compute
Compute
24
```

I tried with `Promise`:

```
    val p = for {
      p <- Promise.make[Nothing, Int]
      _ <- p.succeed {
        println(s"Compute - P")
        48
      }
      r <- p.await
    } yield {
      r
    }

    val r = unsafeRun(for {
      tt1 <- p
      tt2 <- p
    } yield {
      tt1 + tt2
    })
```

And I get the same issue:

```
Compute - P
Compute - P
96
```

I tried with

```
    val p = for {
      p <- Promise.make[Nothing, Int]
      _ <- p.succeed(48)
      r <- p.await
    } yield {
      println(s"Compute - P")
      r
    }
```

first and I was thinking that maybe the pipeline is executed but not the value recomputed but I does not work either.

I would like to be able to compute asynchronously my values and be able to reuse them.
I looked at [How do I make a Scalaz ZIO lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851349/how-do-i-make-a-scalaz-zio-lazy/53869931#53869931) but it does not work for me either.

Comment: I do not know if Zio has such capability _(maybe it does for performance reasons)_. But, it is important that you know that doing that will break the **referential transparency** principle, which in some sense, it is the main reason for using any kind of `IO` **Monad**. If you do not care about that, and only want asynchronous computations, then just use `Future`.

Comment: Monix `Task` has `memoize` method, maybe use it instead?

Answer (score 7):

ZIO has [memoize](https://static.javadoc.io/dev.zio/zio_2.12/1.0.0-RC9-4/zio/ZIO.html#memoize:zio.ZIO[R,Nothing,zio.IO[E,A]]), which should do essentially what you want.  I don't have a way to test it just now, but it should work something like:

```
for {
  memoized <- t.memoize
  tt1 <- memoized
  tt2 <- memoized
} yield tt1 + tt2
```

Note that unless the second and third lines of your real code have some branching that might result in the `Task` never getting called, or getting called only once, this yields the same answer and side effects as the much simpler:

```
t flatMap {tt => tt + tt}
```

Comment: You can probably post this as an answer over at https://stackoverflow.com/q/53851349/14955 as well. I was trying to manually implement `memoize` there before it was available. I wonder if it works similarly.

Comment: Here is a link to the [ZIO memoize source](https://github.com/zio/zio/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/zio/ZIO.scala#L733-L743)

Comment: @jq170727 So it does do the same thing. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Does computing the results have side effects? If it doesn't you can just use a regular old lazy val, perhaps lifted into `ZIO`.

```
lazy val results = computeResults()
val resultsIO = ZIO.succeedLazy(results)
```

If it does have side effects, you can't really cache the results because that wouldn't be referentially transparent, which is the whole point of `ZIO`.
What you'll probably have to do is `flatMap` on your compute `Task` and write the rest of your program which needs the result of that computation inside that call to `flatMap`, threading the `result` value as a parameter through your function calls where necessary.

```
val compute = Task {
  println(s"Compute")
  12
}

compute.flatMap { result =>
  // the rest of your program
}
```